# Ruby: How to catch custom exception in parent class when it is defined in a sub class

Tags: ruby, exception

I am relatively new to ruby and I am stuck with this problem which is rather hard to solve.

What I want to achieve is that I could catch custom errors which I throw from the sub class in a parent class. Given an example below, how could I make the parent class to understand the `RequestTimeout` class? Because, now when I run the code it results to a following output:

```
test_raise.rb:5:in `rescue in handle_errors': uninitialized constant BaseService::RequestTimeout (NameError)
    from test_raise.rb:4:in `handle_errors'
    from test_raise.rb:14:in `first_service_method'
    from test_raise.rb:31:in `<main>'
```

The code:

```
class BaseService

  def handle_errors
    yield
  rescue RequestTimeout => e # <-- the problem
    p e.message
  end
end

class FirstService < BaseService
    class RequestTimeout < StandardError; end

    def first_service_method
        handle_errors do
            raise RequestTimeout, "FirstService RequestTimeout"
        end
    end
end

class SecondService < BaseService
    class RequestTimeout < StandardError; end

    def second_service_method
        handle_errors do
            raise RequestTimeout, "SecondService RequestTimeout"
        end
    end
end

a = FirstService.new
a.first_service_method
```

Ofc. I could solve the problem by changing:

```
rescue RequestTimeout => e
```

to:

```
rescue => e
```

But I dont want to do that because I wan't to catch multiple exceptions (more than RequestTimeout) which are defined and raised by me. Any help would be awesome!

Comment: Move `class RequestTimeout < StandardError; end` into **base** class. It will become available in all children. Whether you have different exceptions for different child classes, you are forced to use namespaces, as @marek-lipka said below.

Comment: @mudasobwa Yea, thats what I ended up doing - I worried about doing it earlier as it seemed that rails rescue_from catched errors which wasn't from the class it was throwing from. However, I am having trouble of repeating that. So If you are so kind and post your comment as an answer I accept that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an option to move

```
class RequestTimeout < StandardError; end
```

declaration into the base class. It hence will become available to all children.

Whether you have different exceptions for different child classes, you are forced to use namespaces, as @Marek said in sibling comment.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is about namespaces - `RequestTimeout` is defined in different namespace than `BaseService`. You should have:

```
rescue FirstService::RequestTimeout => e
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but if I have 10 or more classes extending base service you could see how bad the code is going to look like in the BaseService? :S rescue FirstService::RequestTimeout .. SecondService::RequestTimeout ... etc.. is there are other way? Like dynamically accessing X::RequestTimeout or similar? How I can teach upper class to understand that he owns RequestTimeout? :( Moreover, if BaseService is provided by API and sub class (3rd party) is using  it there is no change the API provider would modify the upper class all the time :/ ?

Comment: I came to in conclusion that what I wanted to do in my brains wasn't possible with ruby. So I am giving you +1 for the effort because I can't deny that you are wrong either. Best possible solution however were the one which @mudasobwa pointed out.